# Cannot get current user with guardian

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm using [Guardian](https://github.com/ueberauth/guardian) and trying to use [Canary](https://github.com/cpjk/canary) however, I can't seem to fetch the current user, canary needs the current_user in conn.assigns, I've followed [this](http://learningelixir.joekain.com/using-guardian-and-canary-with-phoenix/), if I ask for (inside a controller action):

```
Guardian.Plug.authenticated?(conn)
```

I get true, but if I do:

```
Guardian.Plug.current_resource(conn)
```

It's just blank.

I have this code in my api pipeline:

```
pipeline :private_api do
  plug :accepts, ["json"]
  plug Guardian.Plug.LoadResource
  plug Guardian.Plug.VerifyHeader

  plug Guardian.Plug.EnsureAuthenticated, handler: SessionController
  plug MyApp.Plug.CurrentUser
end
```

and in for MyApp.Plug.CurrentUser

```
defmodule MyApp.Plug.CurrentUser do
  def init(opts), do: opts

  def call(conn, _opts) do
    current_user = Guardian.Plug.current_resource(conn)
    Plug.Conn.assign(conn, :current_user, current_user)
  end
end
```

Session create method:

```
 def create(conn, %{"session" => session_params}) do
    case MyApp.Session.authenticate(session_params) do
      {:ok, user} ->
        {:ok, jwt, _full_claims} = user |> Guardian.encode_and_sign(:token)

        Plug.Conn.assign(conn, :current_user, user)

        conn
        |> put_status(:created)
        |> render("show.json", jwt: jwt, user: user)

      :error ->
        conn
        |> put_status(:unprocessable_entity)
        |> render("error.json")
    end
  end
```

Maybe I'm just missing something.

Comment: Try change code in pipeline to VerifyHeader first, then LoadResource

Comment: I have the same issue. Where you able to solve it?

Comment: It works for me as described in the last code block

Comment: The problem is that you call `Guardian.decode_and_verify` which is already done, i believe by `Guardian.Plug.EnsureAuthenticated`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While not ideal, this was my solution, this question does not accept more answers since it is way too old to even validate that the answers work:

```
defmodule MyApp.Plug.CurrentUser do
  alias MyApp.GuardianSerializer
  def init(opts), do: opts

  def call(conn, _opts) do
    current_token = Guardian.Plug.current_token(conn)
    case Guardian.decode_and_verify(current_token) do
      {:ok, claims} ->
        case GuardianSerializer.from_token(claims["sub"]) do
          {:ok, user} ->
            Plug.Conn.assign(conn, :current_user, user)
          {:error, _reason} ->
            conn
        end
      {:error, _reason} ->
        conn
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

For latest releases of `Guardian`, this is the working code:

```
defmodule MyApp.Plugs.CurrentUser do
  def init(opts), do: opts

  def call(conn, _opts) do
   current_token = Guardian.Plug.current_token(conn)
    case MyApp.Guardian.resource_from_token(current_token) do
      {:ok, user, claims} ->
            Plug.Conn.assign(conn, :current_user, user)
      {:error, _reason} ->
        conn
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: This code seems to be right, but why build custom plug when Guardian provides one already https://hexdocs.pm/guardian/2.3.2/Guardian.Plug.LoadResource.html

Answer (score -1):

According to the docs this is how [pipline](https://hexdocs.pm/guardian/readme.html#pipelines) should be configured:

```
defmodule MyApp.AuthAccessPipeline do
  use Guardian.Plug.Pipeline, otp_app: :my_app

  plug Guardian.Plug.VerifySession, claims: %{"typ" => "access"}
  plug Guardian.Plug.VerifyHeader, claims: %{"typ" => "access"}
  plug Guardian.Plug.EnsureAuthenticated
  plug Guardian.Plug.LoadResource, allow_blank: true
end
```

The `Guardian.Plug.LoadResource` is missing in your pipline. It uses function `resource_from_claims` from your Gauradian module (you have to implement it) to fetch the resource and stores it to `conn`. You are tring to do this job using `MyApp.Plug.CurrentUser`.

Read the [docs](https://hexdocs.pm/guardian/readme.html#installation) carefully.

1. Provide implementation for you guardian module first.
2. Configure your pipline to use your implementation module.
3. Make sure all is configured well according the docs

> The `claims[sub]` should rather contain only id. Than use that id to load resource possibly from database.

Comment: The post is almost 8 years old :)

Comment: This answer doesn't add value to this question since the version is way too old to even compare it, I don't recall if I got to test the solution provided in the other post as it was posted a year after the question was created...